# Center an Inline-block div in between two floated divs inside a footer

Tags: css, css-float, footer

I have 3 divs inside the footer: One **Floated left**, One in the middle with **display-inline: block; and float left;** and one in the end **floated right**.

http://jsfiddle.net/qmwfbhtx/1/

So far I tried to add min-width of **45%** to the div on the left, but that just causes problems when resizing. So..

**How can I fully-center the middle div in between two divs?**

I'm trying to find a solution based on floats and display:inline-block instead of Flexbox.

```css
.copyright {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.miamilove {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.termslist {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}
.footcol a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.footwrap {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid footwrap">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="footcol">

      <span class="copyright">Copyrr Inc. &copy; 2016</span> 

    </div>


    <div class="footcol">

      <span class="miamilove">Made With <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> in Hollywood</span> 

    </div>


    <div class="footcol termslist">

      <a href="#">Investors</a>


      <a href="#">Press</a>



      <a href="#">Blog</a>



      <a href="#">Sign up</a>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless i misunderstood, you might need the flex properties.

```
.row {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qmwfbhtx/2/

Comment: The flex-property doesnt work when you resize the window. How can I make the words moves to the next line without crunching together?

Comment: @user3771570 you mean something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/qmwfbhtx/3/ (removed most of css unused and margins ) actually we can go down here http://jsfiddle.net/qmwfbhtx/4/

Comment: Great examples! Thanks for helping me figure this out!